# How to set ipc_perm for the default output device?

Tags: alsa

When I use aplay to play some sound, sometimes I get an error:

> ```
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1071:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to create IPC semaphore
> aplay: main:828: audio open error: Permission denied
> ```

This *seems* to happen only when a non-root-user on the host is already playing something and then root in a Docker container starts playing. When root is playing something in the container and then the user starts playing on the host, it works without issues. (The containers runs with `--ipc="host"`.)

I don't quite understand why it fails in exactly this manner, but I would like to try and set the permissions of the IPC semaphore to 666. In `ipcs` I can see that they are currently 660.

For this I need to set `ipc_perm 0666` in the asound.conf, but I don't know how to do that for the *default* device.

I know I can create a *new* device with

```
pcm.foo {
  ipc_perm 0666
}
```

But instead I would like to set it for the default device, without deleting the rest of the default device config.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I noticed that I already had

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

in my `asound.conf` to select the hardware device for the default output device.

So with more luck than judgement I tried

```
defaults.pcm.ipc_perm 0666
```

and it worked.